# SQL Server Convert date time to n period ago

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a field **lastLogin** which is datetime.
I want to show the user his/her last login time as
**n years ago**, if it is less that 1 year than
**n months ago**, if it is less that 1 month than
**n days ago**, if it is less that 1 day than
**n hours ago**, if it is less that 1 hour than
**n minutes ago**, if it is less that 1 minutes than
**n seconds ago**

I want that the **s** in years , months , days , hours , minures and seconds are handled automatically as the rules of English Grammar.

i am a complete beginner in sql and i am using **SQL SERVER 2008 R2**

Comment: This seems a lot like homework. What have you tried? This really isn't too complicated, but the code is going to get length with those requirements. You will need to do a lot of math and case expressions.

Comment: Very true, this is tedious job but easy for you.  Please send a short script as to how to proceed . Is if else will suffice. I haven't done anything yet but  for small code you will be doing me a favour,

Comment: This sounds like a presentation concern, therefore this is better done at the client application side.

Comment: I Agree with you. But my problem is i am using ASP.NET gridview to show lastlogin and i am using EVAL but i don't know how to call method from aspx page on EVAL or BIND. So i have to use it from BackEnd.

Comment: Should that not read **n years ago** if it is more than 1 year?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with nested IIF() function and using DATEDIFF() and GETDATE().

```
SELECT 
    IFF(DATEDIFF(second, lastLogin, GETDATE()) < 60, 
        CONCAT(DATEDIFF(second, lastLogin, GETDATE()), ' seconds ago'),
        IFF(DATEDIFF(minute, lastLogin, GETDATE()) < 60, 
            CONCAT(DATEDIFF(minute, lastLogin, GETDATE()), ' minutes ago'),
            IIF( .....continue with the nested conditions until years....) 
        )
    ) AS lastloginstring
FROM .....
```

As you can see the query will become long and clumsy. It is still better to do it on the view level.

You can consider defining your function with CREATE FUNCTION that would accept as parameter a DATETIME  value and return the needed string. Then in the SELECT statement you would use only SELECT yourfunctionname(lastLogin) FROM. The definition of the function could follow the same model as above - nedted IIFs or IF THEN ELSE statements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CASE` statement

```
CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(yy, lastLogin, GETDATE()) > 1 THEN CASE(DATEDIFF(yy, lastLogin, GETDATE()) AS varchar(5) + ' years ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(y, lastLogin, GETDATE()) = 1 THEN '1 year ago'
    -- ... and so on
END AS LastLoginPeriod
```

Not tested and written in a hurry as supper is ready!

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FUNCTION fngettimeinagoformat(@givenDate DateTime,@curDate DateTime)
RETURNS Varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Date as Varchar(100)
  SELECT @Date = 
  CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(ss,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 1 THEN '1 Sec ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(ss,@givenDate,@curDate) > 1 AND DATEDIFF(ss,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 60 THEN CONVERT(Varchar,DATEDIFF(ss,@givenDate,@curDate)) + ' Sec ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(mi,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 1 THEN '1 min ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(mi,@givenDate,@curDate) > 1 AND DATEDIFF(mi,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 60 THEN CONVERT(Varchar,DATEDIFF(mi,@givenDate,@curDate)) + ' mins ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(hh,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 1 THEN CONVERT(Varchar,DATEDIFF(hh,@givenDate,@curDate)) + ' hour ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(hh,@givenDate,@curDate) > 1 AND DateDiff(hh,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 24 THEN CONVERT(Varchar,DATEDIFF(hh,@givenDate,@curDate)) + ' hrs ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 1 THEN CONVERT(Varchar,DATEDIFF(dd,@givenDate,@curDate)) + ' day ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(dd,@givenDate,@curDate) > 1 AND  DATEDIFF(dd,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 7 THEN CONVERT(Varchar,DATEDIFF(dd,@givenDate,@curDate)) + ' days ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(ww,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 1 THEN CONVERT(Varchar,DATEDIFF(ww,@givenDate,@curDate)) + ' week ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(ww,@givenDate,@curDate) > 1 AND DATEDIFF(ww,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 4 THEN CONVERT(Varchar,DATEDIFF(ww,@givenDate,@curDate)) + ' weeks ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(mm,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 1 THEN CONVERT(Varchar,DATEDIFF(mm,@givenDate,@curDate)) + ' month ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(mm,@givenDate,@curDate) > 1 AND DATEDIFF(mm,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 12 THEN CONVERT(Varchar,DATEDIFF(mm,@givenDate,@curDate)) + ' mnths ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(yy,@givenDate,@curDate) <= 1 THEN CONVERT(Varchar,DATEDIFF(yy,@givenDate,@curDate)) + ' year ago'
    WHEN DATEDIFF(yy,@givenDate,@curDate) > 1 THEN CONVERT(Varchar,DATEDIFF(yy,@givenDate,@curDate)) + ' yrs ago'
  END
  RETURN @Date
END
```