# ASP.NET GridView Eval with function n period ago

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I want to show **lastlogin** which is stored in **sql server** in **datetime**.
as
**n years ago**, if it is less that 1 year than
**n months ago**, if it is less that 1 month than
**n days ago**, if it is less that 1 day than
**n hours ago**, if it is less that 1 hour than
**n minutes ago**, if it is less that 1 minutes than
**n seconds ago**

I want that the **s** in years , months , days , hours , minutes and seconds are handled automatically as the rules of English Grammar.
I wanted a **sql stored procedure** for that but answers on my question suggest that i should use this code on view level.

[SQL Server Convert date time to n period ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35802714/sql-server-convert-date-time-to-n-period-ago/)

Suppose my function `ShowPeriod()` is in the **cs codebehind** file  and i have a label in the **aspx** page.

will `Text = "ShowPeriod(<%#Eval('lastLogin')%>)"` will suffice? or is it illegal to use.

Comment: It seems you are posting essentially duplicate question. Please show your code instead of the link and ask a specific question. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use stored procedure?

Comment: Yes , My teacher told me to use stored procedure. As it is much efficient than plain query.

Comment: Now i want to use my function is the given code is sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more like:

```
Text='<%# ShowPeriod(Eval("lastLogin")) %>'
```

And ShowPeriod must be Protected or Public.